# Using Be or Being for initial word

Tags: be, when, being

I don't know which word is right for this sentence:

> Be at the airport by 4 o'clock to meet him when his flight lands.

or

> Being at the airport by 4 o'clock to meet him when his flight lands.

Are these imperative sentences or any other kind of sentence?

Comment: *(You are supposed to)* be at  the airport.....

Comment: We don't do homework here.

Comment: I believe this question would be better suited for the ELL stack.  No offense @Kaiii.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence, *Be at the airport...* is an imperative sentence; you tell someone that they should do something. However, it can also be interpreted as a non-finite clause (see below). The correct analysis depends on the context. Here is an example as an imperative:

> "Be at the airport to meet him!"
>   "OK, I will be there."

The second sentence is a non-finite clause (*Being at the airport...*) followed by an infinitive clause (*to meet him...*). It does not contain a finite verb, and so is not a fully grammatical sentence. It could be used in conversation as a reply to a question, as in spoken language you often infer parts of the sentence from context. But even then the second sentence still sounds a bit odd, and you would typically prefer the first sentence:

> Q: "What did I ask you to do?"
>   A: "Be at the airport to meet him."
>
> Q:"What was your task for today?"
>   A: "Being at the airport by 4 o'clock to meet him."

You would infer "You asked me to..." in the first sentence, and "My task was..." in the second one.

Comment: Which one is correct for general statement? It just such fill the blank question : ''... be at the airport by 4 o'clock to meet him when his flight lands'' , and the option : be/being/have been/to be/been

Comment: @Kaiii If by "general statement" you mean "correct stand-alone sentence", then _be_ would be the best answer.